# How do I format data I have received from a scanner in google scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on a scanner that receives data and sends it to my google sheets. I use this for my robotics for scouting on other teams. I have a dilemma where the data it receives all dumps into one cell, alongside the time scanned. the data looks like this:
`Team Number*7@Color*Red^Power-cells Upper: *0^Power-cells Bottom: *0^Power-cells Upper: *1^Power-cells Bottom: *0^Enter Your Name*Name^Score of Red Alliance*95^Score of Blue Alliance*27^Personal Notes*Movement seems lagged and almost tipped over^Spun the color wheel more than 3 times and less than 5 times*0^Spun the Color Wheel to the correct color*0^Is Defended on*0^Bumps into other Bots*0^Description*Nothing/Broke^Defense*0^Climb_Quality*1^Speed*1^Pickup*2^^^Result*Lose^Stage*1^` The carets are supposed to indicate when the data should move over into the next cell. Here is the code in google scripts:

```
function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("My Sheet");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 return insert(e,sheet);


}

function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("My Sheet");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return insert(e,sheet);

}

function insert(e,sheet) {

  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var d = new Date();
  var ctime =  d.toLocaleString();

sheet.appendRow([scannedData,ctime]);

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput("Success")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  

}
```

As stated before, the problem is that it dumps the data into a single cell, and I am looking on how to make the carets indicate that it puts the data a cell over automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function loadWierdData() {
  var s="Team Number*7@Color*Red^Power-cells Upper: *0^Power-cells Bottom: *0^Power-cells Upper: *1^Power-cells Bottom: *0^Enter Your Name*Name^Score of Red Alliance*95^Score of Blue Alliance*27^Personal Notes*Movement seems lagged and almost tipped over^Spun the color wheel more than 3 times and less than 5 times*0^Spun the Color Wheel to the correct color*0^Is Defended on*0^Bumps into other Bots*0^Description*Nothing/Broke^Defense*0^Climb_Quality*1^Speed*1^Pickup*2^^^Result*Lose^Stage*1^"; 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var vA=[];
  var s0=s.split('^');
  s0.forEach(function(r){
    var a=r.split('*');
    if(a[0]) {
      vA.push({header:a[0],data:a.slice(1).join(',')});
    }
  });
  var hA=vA.map(function(o,i){return o.header;});
  var rA=vA.map(function(o,i){return o.data;});
  if(sh.getLastRow()==0) {
    sh.appendRow(hA);
    sh.appendRow(rA)
  }else{

    sh.appendRow(rA);
  }
}
```